# How can I find which dbgsym packages I need to obtain symbolic stack traces?

Tags: debian, debugging, core-dump

I have a core file on a Debian system. I want to obtain a complete list of all debug symbol packages needed to generate a symbolic stack trace from that core dump.

By what means can I generate such a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Debian `buster`, you can use [`find-dbgsym-packages`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debian-goodies/find-dbgsym-packages.1.en.html) from the [`debian-goodies`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/debian-goodies) package.

> **find-dbgsym-packages** lists all *-dbgsym packages required to properly debug processes given by a list of executables, libraries, core dumps or PID numbers.

Answer (score 3):

`readelf -Wa` will give detailed information about a core dump, including the mapped files (look for `NT_FILE`). You should install the debug symbols for any file which is a binary or a library. To find the relevant packages, install `apt-file` if you haven’t already, run `sudo apt update` to update its indexes, and run

```
apt-file search /path/to/file
```

For example, if `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.7.1` shows up in the list of mapped files in a given core dump,

```
$ apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.7.1
libpcre2-8-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.7.1
```

By extension, this tells you that you need to install `libpcre2-8-0-dbgsym` to have the corresponding debug symbols.

(Yes, this is somewhat more cumbersome than it should be. Other distributions make this simpler...)